# getting error while declaring vector of vector

Tags: c++, vector

Is this wrong method of declaring vector of vector

```
vector<vector<bool>> visited(100, vector<bool>(100,false));
```

getting error as:

```
 Line 5: Char 34: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
 vector<vector<bool>> visited(100, vector<bool>(100,false));
```

i declared it in starting of solution class

in below program

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;


class Solution {
public:
    int nr,nc;
    //vector<vector<bool>> visited(1000,vector<bool>(1000,false)) ;
    vector<vector<bool>> visited(100, vector<bool>(100,false));
    bool dfs(vector<vector<char>>& board,string word,int i,int j,int cr){
        visited[i][j]=true;
        if(cr==word.length())
            return true;
        if(cr>word.length())
            return false;
        if(j+1<nc && board[i][j+1]==word[cr] && !visted[i][j+1])
            return dfs(board,word,i,j+1,cr+1);
        if(j-1>=0 && board[i][j-1]==word[cr] && !visited[i][j-1])
            return dfs(board,word,i,j-1,cr+1);
        if(i+1<nr && board[i+1][j]==word[cr] && !visited[i+1][j])
            return dfs(board,word,i+1,j,cr+1);
        if(i-1>=0 && board[i-1][j]==word[cr] && !visited[i-1][j])
            return dfs(board,word,i-1,j,cr+1);
        return false;
    }
   bool dfs_help(vector<vector<char>> &board,string word){
       for(int i=0;i<board.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<board[0].size();j++){
                    visited[i][j]=false;
                }
            }
        }



       for(int i=0;i<board.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<board[0].size();j++){
                if(board[i][j]==word[0]){
                    visited[i][j]=true;
                    if(dfs(board,word,i,j,1))
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
    vector<string> findWords(vector<vector<char>>& board, vector<string>& words) {
        nr = board.size();
        nc = board[0].size();
        vector<string> ans;
        for(string v : words){
            if(dfs_help(board,v))
                ans.push_back(v);
        }
        sort(ans.begin(),ans.end());
        return ans;
    }
};
int main(){

}
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: If you're going to use `std::vector`, then `#include <vector>`, not some other header.

Comment: only while competitive programming @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: There's no such thing like _"competitive programming"_.

Comment: @humblefool -- You want us to duplicate the issue -- well there is no such header as `<bits whatever>` in standard C++, and it doesn't exist in Visual Studio, which is what is being used by many programmers.

Comment: @humblefool: Do you still get the error after replacing the headers?

Comment: Now I changed But problem still persist

Comment: @humblefool Hint -- you do not construct member variables (vectors) like that.  "Competitive programming" doesn't teach basic C++ skills.  Use the [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: When you believe the type is relevant, try something similar with a primitive type before jumping to conclusions. You would encounter the same issue if you wrote `class A { int x(0);};`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to construct a member variable such as `std::vector` with sizing arguments, the way you do that is to use the member initialization list of the `Solution` constructor.

To do this, you should remove the line that is giving the error, and instead add a default constructor to `Solution` so that the member(s) can be initialized:

```
class Solution
{
   //...
   Solution() : visited(100, std::vector<bool>(100,false)), nr(0), nc(0) {}
   //...
};
```